# Accessibility: Mouse Pointer goes back to default Size during Screen Sharing (or Jump Desktop)

Tags: mouse, accessibility, cursor

I need to have the mouse pointer larger than normal (I also use different colors).  But when I screen share from Mac to Mac (both running **Monterey**), the cursor is the tiny default size.

If I go into accessibility, the slider is still over to the right (large), and I even try moving it.

I'm having this with both Mac's built-in screen share, and using Jump Desktop.

I've also tried changing the "scaling" in the settings, but didn't make any difference.

And what's really weird, even though the size is ignored, it DOES display the cursor in my alternate colors, just really small.

Comment: What are the cursor settings in the other Mac? Are they the same?

Comment: Yes, I use the 2nd to largest click in the Accessibility control panel horizontal slider on both Macs.  And same colors, etc.

Comment: Sigh... no answers, nobody to reward with bounty

Comment: If somebody reads this later and has the answer, I might be willing to put up another bounty to reward.  I'd like a fix/workaround, vs. just a message confirming it's a known bug.

Comment: In Novemeber 2023 on Sonoma 14.1 this is still an issue. 